# How to get all the xtypes of a certain type

Tags: extjs4

I have a panel which has items as follows:

```
                {
                    xtype: "panel",
                    border: 0,
                    defaultType: "textfield",
                    bodyStyle: "background: transparent;",
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: "100%",
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    margin: "2 4px",
                    layout: "hbox",
                    flex: 2,
                    items: [
                        {xtype: "searchvaluefield"}, {xtype: "random" }, {xtype: "searchvaluefield"}
                    ],

                }
```

However these items consist of a dynamic number of elements. In particular there can be an arbitrary number of the xtype "searchvaluefield". I wish to get an array of all the elements in this panel which are of xtype "searchvaluefield". Note I have simplified the problem and the actual problem contains multiple panels within panels which is why I was hoping to avoid looping through things.

If it helps here is the defined xtype I am seeking:

```
    Ext.define("app.view.stock.SearchValueField", {
        extend: "Ext.form.field.Text",
        alias: "widget.searchvaluefield",
        name: "search_value_field",
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        allowBlank: false,
        initComponent: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by using [query](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-query) method for the panel

`yourPanel.query('searchvaluefield');` - returns an array of items matching that xtype.

Comment: Short but great answer!!